# Keyboard maestro: Defining "if app active" macros

Tags: keyboard, automation

In Keyboard Maestro, is there any way to define a macro that is triggered when two conditions are true?

- A certain application is active (i.e. on focus)
- A hot key is activated (i.e. I press a key)

I have tried adding conditions, but they are interpreted with an `OR` and not with an `AND`.

Below is an example of what I tried:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To define Keyboard Maestro macros only active in specific applications you need to define a new Macro Group (left most column in the Keyboard Maestro Editor) and select the application(s) on group level.

[image]